# AWS Cognito - Can I use the migration trigger in a Custom auth flow

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-net

I am investigating the recently released migration trigger for cognito user pools. To enable the trigger you need to set the AuthFlow type in the InitiateAuthRequest to be "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH" see here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-import-using-lambda.html

I want to use the custom auth flow so that I can return a challenge response for email verification is the users are not email verified from the existing user store. However if I set the AuthFlow type to "CUSTOM_AUTH" then the migration trigger is not fired.

Is there a way to get custom auth and migration working at the same time?

Example code:

```
var client = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);

var authRequest = new InitiateAuthRequest
{
    ClientId = "*********",
    AuthFlow = "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH" // Or AuthFlow = "CUSTOM_AUTH"
};

authRequest.AuthParameters.Add("USERNAME", username);
authRequest.AuthParameters.Add("PASSWORD", password);

var response = await client.InitiateAuthAsync(authRequest);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am on the Cognito team and that is not possible at this point. I can however mention your use case within the team as a feature request.

Comment: Thanks, is there a roadmap for features that might be coming out in Cognito? seems like there is a lot of feature requests like this across stackoverflow, github etc.

Comment: In general, we don't usually communicate on the availability of features or give out timelines for features.

Comment: Seems like this is still not possible as of 01/2020. I guess batch import of all users beforehand is the only way to go.